# Facebook Graph API: Miscellaneous UserId

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When exploring the Facebook Graph API, at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer The default example is get my `name & id` (under the assumption the browsers logged to my Facebook account). All good and I get my correct `Id` (`facebook.com/id` redirect to my profile).

So here is the thing: Exploring network traffic via developer console, I noticed some ajax have user id as url param, and the id is totally different from the previous one:

1. Same length
2. Much more zeros

So I tried same thing: `facebook.com/new_id` and same result: Redirect to my correct profile page.

How is that each user have 2 different id's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s called app-scoped user ids, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api